# I have a dataframe, is it possible to get a matrix with rows as the name of the fruits and the values as frequency of that fruit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame,  is it possible to get a matrix with rows as the name of the fruits and the values as the frequency of that fruit?

```
       a       b       c
0  apple  orange  banana
1   kiwi  orange  orange
2   kiwi  banana   apple
```

---

[Output:]

```
--------------------------------
|       |  a   |   b  |   c    |
--------------------------------
|apple  |  1   |   0  |   1    |
|orange |  0   |   2  |   1    |
|kiwi   |  2   |   0  |   0    |
|banana |  0   |   1  |   1    | 
-------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
new_df = df.melt()
pd.crosstab(new_df['value'],new_df['variable'])

#        a  b  c
#apple   1  0  1
#banana  0  1  1
#kiwi    2  0  0
#orange  0  2  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per each column by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), replace missing values and last values to integers:

```
df1 = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
        a  b  c 
apple   1  0  1
banana  0  1  1
kiwi    2  0  0
orange  0  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

A wider version using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
m = pd.get_dummies(df)
m = pd.wide_to_long(m.reset_index(),['a','b','c'],
             'index','v',sep='_',suffix='\D+').groupby(level=1).sum().rename_axis(None)
```

---

```
 print(m)
        a    b    c
apple   1.0  0.0  1.0
banana  0.0  1.0  1.0
kiwi    2.0  0.0  0.0
orange  0.0  2.0  1.0
```